# Trouble on update tags record by Filament v3 Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I created a form that has a `TagsInput`:

```
    return $form
      ->schema([
        Fieldset::make('details')
          ->schema([
            TextInput::make('title'),
            FileUpload::make('image')
              ->image()
              ->nullable(true)
              ->default(null),
            Select::make('category')
              ->options([
                '1' => '1',
                '2' => '2',
                '3' => '3',
              ]),
            TagsInput::make('keywords'),
          ])->columnSpan([
            'sm' => 12,
          ]),
        RichEditor::make('content')->columnSpan([
          'sm' => 12,
        ]),
        TextInput::make('author')->default(Auth::id())->hidden(),
      ]);
```

At update form I need to keywords (TagsInput) show current record value of `keywords` record from database, but TagsInput is empty. (record from database has valid json value)

What is wrong with that?

Keywords input in update form:

[image]

Keywords data in database:

[image]

other `TextInputs` in update form shows data from database correctly!

Comment: Run `./apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`, it will show you what virtual hosts your apache actually knows about.  "*my domain is not working*" does not give us anything to go on.  You get any messages or logs?  Put your LogLevel to a higher level (ex. trace8) to hopefully see something more.

Comment: I found answer of my question: I added this code on related model eloquent:     protected $casts = [
        'tags' => 'array',
]; as is said in this page of official Filament Tagsinput documentation https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/tags-input